# "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission on Wear OS 4

Tags: android, android-permissions, file-permissions, wear-os

**Description**

I have encountered an issue with granting the "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission on Wear OS 4, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it.

On Wear OS 3, I had no trouble granting this permission, and it worked perfectly for my app. However, after upgrading to Wear OS 4, I've noticed that the "MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission is no longer available even in settings.

Here are some details about my setup:

Wear OS version: 4.0
Target SDK version: 33
Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Permissions checking function:

```
fun checkFilesPermissions(): Boolean {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
    }
```

Comment: and are you having trouble without this permission? in my case the ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION is no longer existing, but my app works just fine. on wear os 3 it did not work without this permission.
now i just check with 
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) { 
and only ask for this permission on the old version.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... the permission seems to take no effect anymore on wear os 4 (my file manager app wasnt showing any files, I had to ask for media permission)... but still I cannot delete or modify any files that was not created by my app (no solution for that yet)...

Answer (score 0):

The one way to use all files permission: ask user to connect watch via adb and write command this command

adb shell appops set --uid com.dertefter.wearfiles MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow

Really sad